# Python remove everything after specific string and loop through all rows in multiple columns in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I have a file full of URL paths like below spanning across 4 columns in a dataframe that I am trying to clean:

```
Path1 = ["https://contentspace.global.xxx.com/teams/Australia/WA/Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx?\
RootFolder=%2Fteams%2FAustralia%2FWA%2FDocuments%2FIn%20Scope&FolderCTID\
=0x012000EDE8B08D50FC3741A5206CD23377AB75&View=%7B287FFF9E%2DD60C%2D4401%2D9ECD%2DC402524F1D4A%7D"]
```

I want to remove everything after a specific string which I defined it as "string1" and I would like to loop through all 4 columns in the dataframe defined as "df_MasterData":

```
string1 = "&FolderCTID"
```

```
import pandas as pd 

df_MasterData = pd.read_excel(FN_MasterData)

cols = ['Column_A', 'Column_B', 'Column_C', 'Column_D']

for i in cols:  

    # Objective: Replace "&FolderCTID", delete all string after
    string1 = "&FolderCTID"

    # Method 1
    df_MasterData[i] = df_MasterData[i].str.split(string1).str[0]
    
    # Method 2
    df_MasterData[i] = df_MasterData[i].str.split(string1).str[1].str.strip()
    
    # Method 3
    df_MasterData[i] = df_MasterData[i].str.split(string1)[:-1]
```

I did search and google and found similar solutions which were used but none of them work.

Can any guru shed some light on this? Any assistance is appreciated.

Added below is a few example rows in column A and B for these URLs:

```
Column_A = ['https://contentspace.global.xxx.com/teams/Australia/NSW/Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx?\
RootFolder=%2Fteams%2FAustralia%2FNSW%2FDocuments%2FIn%20Scope%2FA%20I%20TOPPER%20GROUP&FolderCTID=\
0x01200016BC4CE0C21A6645950C100F37A60ABD&View=%7B64F44840%2D04FE%2D4341%2D9FAC%2D902BB54E7F10%7D',\
'https://contentspace.global.xxx.com/teams/Australia/Victoria/Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder\
=%2Fteams%2FAustralia%2FVictoria%2FDocuments%2FIn%20Scope&FolderCTID=0x0120006984C27BA03D394D9E2E95FB\
893593F9&View=%7B3276A351%2D18C1%2D4D32%2DADFF%2D54158B504FCC%7D']

Column_B = ['https://contentspace.global.xxx.com/teams/Australia/WA/Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx?\
RootFolder=%2Fteams%2FAustralia%2FWA%2FDocuments%2FIn%20Scope&FolderCTID=0x012000EDE8B08D50FC3741A5\
206CD23377AB75&View=%7B287FFF9E%2DD60C%2D4401%2D9ECD%2DC402524F1D4A%7D',\
'https://contentspace.global.xxx.com/teams/Australia/QLD/Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=%\
2Fteams%2FAustralia%2FQLD%2FDocuments%2FIn%20Scope%2FAACO%20GROUP&FolderCTID=0x012000E689A6C1960E8\
648A90E6EC3BD899B1A&View=%7B6176AC45%2DC34C%2D4F7C%2D9027%2DDAEAD1391BFC%7D']
```

Comment: can you post a few rows of that data? I think we solve this in a clean one liner but need to check to be sure.

Comment: Good point @Manakin, I've added a few example rows for Column_A and Column_B at the bottom of the post thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is how i would do it,

first declare a variable with your target columns.
Then use `stack()` and `str.split` to get your target output.
finally, `unstack` and reapply the output to your original df.

```
cols_to_slice = ['ColumnA','ColumnB','ColumnC','ColumnD']
string1 = "&FolderCTID"

df[cols_to_slice].stack().str.split(string1,expand=True)[1].unstack(1)
```

---

[image]

if you want to replace these columns in your target df then simply do -

```
df[cols_to_slice] = df[cols_to_slice].stack().str.split(string1,expand=True)[1].unstack(1)
```

Comment: Thanks @Manakin, your method makes sense and I can make it work for the above example; however, when I tried to implement it in the dataframe, I am getting error "AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'stack'"

Comment: @m_eddielee are you still looping? using this method you have no need to loop.

Answer (score 0):

You should first get the index of string using

```py
indexes = len(string1) + df_MasterData[i].str.find(string1)
# This selected the final location of this string
# if you don't want to add string in result just use below one
indexes = len(string1) + df_MasterData[i].str.find(string1)
```

Now do

```py
df_MasterData[i] = df_MasterData[i].str[:indexes]
```